# create interval with criterion in R

Tags: r, criteria

```
             gdk   frist   pers       start     code  reg  prog       done  omreg
1           FALSE  FALSE 1941-12-23 2011-01-19 MM2001 FFG FRIST 2012-09-21 FALSE
4            TRUE  FALSE 1943-04-04 2011-09-01 MM2001 FFG FRIST 2012-01-11 FALSE
6           FALSE   TRUE 1944-01-27 2013-09-01 MM2001 FFG FRIST 2014-06-12 FALSE
10          FALSE  FALSE 1944-11-01 2010-01-19 MM2001 FFG FRIST 2010-12-17 FALSE
11          FALSE  FALSE 1945-04-21 2009-09-01 MM2001 FFG FRIST 2010-06-14 FALSE
12          FALSE   TRUE 1945-06-13 2013-01-19 MM2001 FFG FRIST 2014-01-13 FALSE
```

above, we have a piece of the head (both)

I have estimated that it takes 160 days for the students to read one semester. And I want to find out which students were approved for 160 days.

I used:

```
gdk<-(difftime(as.Date(both$done), 
as.Date(both$start), units="days") < 160 & !both$omreg)
```

but right now I want to add a criterion for this range.

variable prog = which program students study
Here is all the programs;

```
FRIST LARAA NASTK NBFFK NBIBK NDATK NFYSK NMATK NMETK NMFIK NSFYY SMEKK
```

so if the student reads FRIST or NDATK they should be <320 days

for LARAA NASTK NBFFK NBIBK NFYSK NMATK NMETK NMFIK NSFYY SMEKK

it should still be <160

**I simply want to have a similar column that gdk with true and false if students meet the criteria. But I want them to be adapted to this criterion. How do I?**

Answer (score 1):

Just put the `ifelse` instead of `160`:

```
( difftime(as.Date(both$done), as.Date(both$start), units="days") < 
    ifelse(both$prog %in% c("FRIST", "NDATK"), 320, 160) & 
    !both$omreg)
```